# How do you remove a lock ring if there is no place to squeeze it?

Tags: transmission, tools

This lock ring holds an overdrive piston in place. I have a set of lock ring pliers but there is nothing to grab onto. There is a gap in the ring but all I can figure out how to do there is expand the ring which doesn't do any good. I could pry it out but the metal is very soft and would get all banged up.

How can I get this lock ring out?

[image]
[image]

**My solution**: This plus put a flathead in the notch on the ring and twist plus a little bit of prying. Then work it around and eventually rotate the ring out by hand. ...A sliver of aluminum came out on the bottom edge of a small part of the ring's channel but I am pretty sure its okay.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used to use a hook type tool to bring the first bit of the clip away from its slot then slide a suitable feeler blade or very small bladed screw driver down behind the created gap. Continue to slide the hook and feeler around until the clip comes free.. Put a cloth over the clip when it gets close  to coming out as you don't want it pinging off somewhere or hitting you in the face.

Comment: This is pretty much how I do it as well.  Done carefully, you won't damage much - and keep in mind even if you make some scratches, this is an area where the piston does not ever normally go (hopefully!) and is of no consequence.  The suggestion for eye protection is a valid one and should be observed.  Them puppies come off with angry vengence.  **PahTINGGG!** and it shoots *somehwere* (you maybe hear it land and bounce twice) and then you might spend an hour trying to find it/fish it out of inaccesible place, Loud violent cursing will help.  Not.  Not like you can go grab one at Autozone!

Comment: Otherwise known as "Jesus clips" as in "Jesus where did that go" , also eye protection is a MUST. +1 anyway.